# How to prevent MongoDB NodeJS driver converts Long into number?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

When querying with `mongodb` driver in NodeJS, the `Long` field may become a number.

```js
// "mongodb": "^4.13.0"
// import { Long } from "mongodb";
await collection.insertOne({
    test: Long.fromNumber(24),
});
const rec = await collection.findOne({ test: Long.fromNumber(24) }, {});
if (rec === null) throw Error("not found");
console.log(typeof rec.test); // number
console.log(rec.test);
```

Only when the long value is large, the query result has a `Long` object.

```js
await collection.insertOne({
    test: Long.MAX_VALUE,
});
const rec = await collection.findOne({ test: Long.MAX_VALUE }, {});
if (rec === null) throw Error("not found");
console.log(typeof rec.test); // object
console.log(rec.test); // Long(...)
```

This makes processing the query result more complex since I need to handle two possible types. And this behaviour is not documented as far as I know, which shoots my foot.

How can I disable this conversion and let it returns `Long` no matter what value it is?

Answer (score 0):

Outside of modifying the driver, the constructor for Long will accept a Long, so you could explicitly set the field upon read,like

```
rec.test = Long(rec.test.toString())
```

This will ensure that rec.test contains a Long.